# IMAP mail sampler load testing using JMeter for increasing the fetchsize

Tags: performance, jmeter, imap

I have a load test scenario wherein I'm testing the IMAP server using the mail read sampler. During the test it was observed to fetch the mail with large attachments (like 120kb) the JMeter client downloaded the content in chunks of 16kb size which in turn increases the overall response time. Is there any way we can increase the default size of'mail.imap.fetchsize' property in the script/jmeter properties from 16kb ?

Comment: [setProperty](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [MailReaderSampler source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/src/protocol/mail/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/mail/sampler/MailReaderSampler.java#L158) - the relevant [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class instance only operates a pre-defined properties set like `starttls.enable`, `starttls.enable`, etc.

The options are in:

1. Patch the aforementioned class source and add `mail.imap.fetchsize` property to the code, recompile JMeter and use it for testing.
2. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) from the Mail Reader Sampler - this way you will have full control over the IMAP [Session](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/Session.html)

You can also raise an [enhancement request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_severity=Enhancement&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&cmdtype=doit&order=Bug%20Number&product=JMeter) and hope that JMeter developers will consider it and include into next release.